# How can i split a text file in many files but the separation would be a specific string?

Tags: c#, wpf, file, text

I´m trying to split a big text file in many files, but each 600-700-900 lines (could be less or more) I have a string that says "Finished File", how can I do it using C#?

Comment: Use 'split' and create new files for each fragment.

Comment: Are you trying to read past the Finished file or stop there?

Comment: Look at [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816149).  That should get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that should work for you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplicationExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Runner r = new Runner();
            r.SplitFile(@"C:\path\to\my\file.txt");
        }
    }

    public class Runner
    {
        private readonly string m_delimiter;

        public Runner()
        {
            m_delimiter = "Finished File";
        }

        public void SplitFile(string inputFile)
        {
            try
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputFile);
                StreamWriter writer;

                int i = 1;                              // count up for every output   file, auto-numbering from 1
                string line;                    
                do
                {
                    string outputFile = GenerateFileName(inputFile, i);
                    writer = new StreamWriter(outputFile);

                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (line.CompareTo(m_delimiter) == 0)
                        {
                            writer.Close();
                            break;                      // breaking will exit the  while-loop & increment i to build a new output file name
                        }
                        else
                            writer.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                    i++;
                } while (line != null);
                writer.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error splitting file: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private string GenerateFileName(string inputFile, int i)
        {
            string folder = Path.GetFullPath(inputFile);
            string fileNameNoExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(inputFile);
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(inputFile);
            return folder + fileNameNoExt + "." + i.ToString("000") + ext;          //  zero-pads "000"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 That you actually spent the time to write this guys program for him.

Comment: thanks, I wrote the general code from another project of mine. took just a few minutes to help him.

Comment: plus, as easy as it sounds, it's not a trivial problem in C#